# Database displaying/allowing different users certain information based on their role or ID

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

Im needing a system as such - they have sales, project management and service management. Each different type of employee should be able to see all information from other employees but only be able to modify the specific information for their job (example is sales cant modify the project management information but can view it). To twist this up a little more, they have multiple locations and only those locations can access data specific to that location.

Since I am most versed in C# I will be using this as the language to tie it all in together.

I have a few different ideas on how to do this and have no idea what would be the best solution to get this all done.

My current idea is for the database...

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
  Employee_ID INT, --PK
  Employee_Role INT, --FK
  Location_ID INT --FK
);
```

Then, each query in the code would be specific to their Employee_Role and Location_ID. I am assuming I would manually create each user (they only have about 15 employees), assign them the values and then have the back-end code tie the queries together.

Difficulty with this is that these system queries are going to get pretty nasty (at least for me, I am not a DBA and have never done something like this).

So for example, if I wanted to display.. lets say Prospective_Clients Table for a specific location I would...and this is roughly my idea

```
SELECT *
FROM Prospective_Clients
    INNER JOIN Employee on Prospective_Clients.Location_ID = Employee.Location_ID;
```

Or something to that effect.. And then to update or insert data, the query would contain in insert statements that Employee_Role has to equal whatever value I assign it. Of course them poses the questions...

1. Would each time an employee insert client information they have to add the location_id as well? I imagine I can just have a drop down they can select that the location name will equal the location_ID... but then there is room for error on the users parts. Or I suppose I could have it set up in the query that the clients Location_ID will equal whatever the employees Location_ID is.
2. Am I going about to right way doing this? Is this all needing to be controlled in the back-end code? Or is there something on the database end that is easier to do this. What I mean by this question is this making sense to anyone the way I am thinking or should I just go find a DBA to hire.

Answer (score 0):

Use a separate table for permission. also make permission based on role not each employee. that's more conformable for end user and developer.

```
CREATE TABLE Role_Permission
(
  RoleID  int, -- fk    
  LocationID  int, -- fk    
  CanAdd  bit,    
  CanRead  bit,    
  CanUpdate  bit ,   
  CanDelete  bit   , 
  Active  bit
)
```